# Using cocoa pod increasing IPA size from 30 MB to 60 MB. Any resolution?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ipa

I am trying to create an IPA file->

```
1. Installed pod -> Added few libraries like Facebook, Twitter, Kingfisher, Fabric etc. -> IPA size with this configuration is 60 MB.
2. Removed pod -> Added static libraries mentioned above -> IPA size reduced to 32 MB.
```

***I want to continue with cocoa pods, as it is helpful for future updates. Any suggestion for reducing IPA size while using IPA. Please do help. Thanks!***